# Can radiant induction heat thermally decompose wood

Tags: heat-transfer, heating-systems, thermal-conduction

Is it possible to thermally decompose an indicator like wood in a induction heating container made of stainless steel if the induction frequency is low enough to heat the container about 1000°c.

Would the radiant heat from the steel cause the wood to heat to a point where they could break down and combust?

Comment: Can you clarify?  First of all, the wood doesn't necessarily 'break down' before combustion.  Next, the wood is always thermally decomposing, just at a very slow rate.  Next, is the container full of normal air?  If so, thermal equilibrium rules will cause the wood to burn long before you reach 1200 K .

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the container would be sealed to be air tight. There would be a little air inside the container but not enough to sustain continued combustion. my concern is that I'm being told that the wood wouldn't break down. The simpler question would be ; can wood be gasified in a sealed metal container with induction heating. I plan to do a few different experiments all with a sealed container; 1. Just regular air at normal pressure, 2. Regular air with the container pressurized, 3. The container is filled with an inert gas such as argon.